# Is there a format specifier in Java String like '%r' in python?

Tags: java, python, string, format

In python, `%r` return `String (converts any Python object using repr()).`

Is there an equivalent format specifier in Java works like that?

What I want to get is sth. like

```
String s = "String s = \"%s\";String.format(s, s)";
return String.Format(s, s);
```

In this way, the output and input are different since it contains escape char `\`. If we have `%r`, we can omit the `\"` part.

Comment: Just find out what I want to achieve is called [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest Java equivalent to Python's `%r` is `%s`.  The `%s` conversion will call either `formatTo()` or `toString()` on the argument, depending on its type.

Note that neither Python's `repr()` or Java's `formatTo()` or `toString()` offers any general guarantees on what is produced.  For example, Python's `repr()` documentation says:

> "**For many types**, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval(), **otherwise** the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object."

and it goes on to say that a class may override the default `repr()` behavior.

In the Java case, the generic `toString()` javadoc is even less prescriptive.

> "Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the `toString` method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read."

Since there is no equivalent to Python's `eval()` in Java, there isn't a general Java SE mechanism for providing escaped representations that can be embedded in generated Java source code.

So the short answer is: No.  Nothing close enough to what you need.